# Hyperledger Fabric: Timeout Expired while starting chaincode on "Peer Chaincode Instantiate" command

Tags: docker, docker-compose, hyperledger-fabric, blockchain, hyperledger

I am trying to instantiate an installed chaincode using the "Peer Chaincode Instantiate" command (as below). On execution of the command, I am receiving the following error message:

**Command to instantiate chaincode:**

```
peer chaincode instantiate -o orderer.proofofownership.com:7050 --tls --cafile /opt/gopath/src/github.com/hyperledger/fabric/peer/crypto/ordererOrganizations/proofofownership.com/orderers/orderer.proofofownership.com/msp/tlscacerts/tlsca.proofofownership.com-cert.pem -C dmanddis -n CreateDiamond -v 1.0 -c '{"Args":[]}' -P "OR ('DiamondManufacturerMSP.peer','DistributorMSP.peer')"
```

**Error Message received:**

```
Error: Error endorsing chaincode: rpc error: code = Unknown desc = timeout expired while starting chaincode CreateDiamond:1.0(networkid:dev,peerid:peer0.dm.proofofownership.com,tx:1a96ecc8763e214ee543ecefe214df6025f8e98f2449f2b7877d04655ddadb49)
```

I tried rectifying this issue by adding the following attributes in "peer-base.yaml file"

```
- CORE_CHAINCODE_EXECUTETIMEOUT=300s
- CORE_CHAINCODE_DEPLOYTIMEOUT=300s
```

Although, I am still receiving this particular error.

Following are my docker container configurations:

**peer-base.yaml File:**

```
services:
peer-base:
image: hyperledger/fabric-peer:x86_64-1.1.0
environment:
  - CORE_VM_ENDPOINT=unix:///host/var/run/docker.sock
  # the following setting starts chaincode containers on the same
  # bridge network as the peers
  # https://docs.docker.com/compose/networking/
  #- CORE_VM_DOCKER_HOSTCONFIG_NETWORKMODE=proof_of_ownership_pow
  #- CORE_VM_DOCKER_HOSTCONFIG_NETWORKMODE=pow
  #- CORE_LOGGING_LEVEL=INFO
  - CORE_LOGGING_LEVEL=DEBUG
  - CORE_PEER_TLS_ENABLED=true
  - CORE_CHAINCODE_EXECUTETIMEOUT=300s
  - CORE_CHAINCODE_DEPLOYTIMEOUT=300s
  #- CORE_PEER_TLS_ENABLED=false
  - CORE_PEER_GOSSIP_USELEADERELECTION=true
  - CORE_PEER_GOSSIP_ORGLEADER=false
  - CORE_PEER_PROFILE_ENABLED=true
  - CORE_PEER_TLS_CERT_FILE=/etc/hyperledger/fabric/tls/server.crt
  - CORE_PEER_TLS_KEY_FILE=/etc/hyperledger/fabric/tls/server.key
  - CORE_PEER_TLS_ROOTCERT_FILE=/etc/hyperledger/fabric/tls/ca.crt
working_dir: /opt/gopath/src/github.com/hyperledger/fabric/peer
command: peer node start
```

**cli - container configuration in "docker-compose-cli.yaml" file:**

```
cli:
container_name: cli
image: hyperledger/fabric-tools:x86_64-1.1.0
tty: true
stdin_open: true
environment:
  - GOPATH=/opt/gopath
  - CORE_VM_ENDPOINT=unix:///host/var/run/docker.sock
  - CORE_LOGGING_LEVEL=DEBUG
  #- CORE_LOGGING_LEVEL=INFO
  - CORE_PEER_ID=cli
  - CORE_PEER_ADDRESS=peer0.dm.proofofownership.com:7051
  - CORE_PEER_LOCALMSPID=DiamondManufacturerMSP
  - CORE_PEER_TLS_ENABLED=true
  - CORE_PEER_TLS_CERT_FILE=/opt/gopath/src/github.com/hyperledger/fabric/peer/crypto/peerOrganizations/dm.proofofownership.com/peers/peer0.dm.proofofownership.com/tls/server.crt
  - CORE_PEER_TLS_KEY_FILE=/opt/gopath/src/github.com/hyperledger/fabric/peer/crypto/peerOrganizations/dm.proofofownership.com/peers/peer0.dm.proofofownership.com/tls/server.key
  - CORE_PEER_TLS_ROOTCERT_FILE=/opt/gopath/src/github.com/hyperledger/fabric/peer/crypto/peerOrganizations/dm.proofofownership.com/peers/peer0.dm.proofofownership.com/tls/ca.crt
  - CORE_PEER_MSPCONFIGPATH=/opt/gopath/src/github.com/hyperledger/fabric/peer/crypto/peerOrganizations/dm.proofofownership.com/users/Admin@dm.proofofownership.com/msp
  - CORE_PEER_CHAINCODELISTENADDRESS=peer0.dm.proofofownership.com:7052
  #- CORE_VM_DOCKER_HOSTCONFIG_NETWORKMODE=host
  #- CORE_VM_DOCKER_HOSTCONFIG_NETWORKMODE=pow
working_dir: /opt/gopath/src/github.com/hyperledger/fabric/peer
command: /bin/bash
volumes:
    - /var/run/:/host/var/run/
    #- ./../chaincode/:/opt/gopath/src/github.com/chaincode
    #- ./chaincode/CreateDiamond/go:/opt/gopath/src/github.com/chaincode/
    - ./chaincode/CreateDiamond:/opt/gopath/src/github.com/hyperledger/fabric/peer/chaincode/
    - ./crypto-config:/opt/gopath/src/github.com/hyperledger/fabric/peer/crypto/
    - ./scripts:/opt/gopath/src/github.com/hyperledger/fabric/peer/scripts/
    - ./channel-artifacts:/opt/gopath/src/github.com/hyperledger/fabric/peer/channel-artifacts
depends_on:
  - orderer.proofofownership.com
  - peer0.dm.proofofownership.com
  - peer1.dm.proofofownership.com 
  - peer0.dist.proofofownership.com
  - peer1.dist.proofofownership.com
#network_mode: host
networks:
  - pow
```

**peer configuration in "docker-compose-base.yaml" file:**

```
peer0.dm.proofofownership.com:
container_name: peer0.dm.proofofownership.com
extends:
  file: peer-base.yaml
  service: peer-base
environment:
  - CORE_PEER_ID=peer0.dm.proofofownership.com
  #- CORE_PEER_MSPCONFIGPATH=/opt/gopath/src/github.com/hyperledger/fabric/peer/crypto/peerOrganizations/dm.proofofownership.com/users/Admin@dm.proofofownership.com/msp
  #- CORE_PEER_MSPCONFIGPATH=/home/john/Proof-Of-Ownership/crypto-config/peerOrganizations/dm.proofofownership.com/users/Admin@dm.proofofownership.com/msp
  - CORE_PEER_ADDRESS=peer0.dm.proofofownership.com:7051
  - CORE_PEER_GOSSIP_BOOTSTRAP=peer0.dm.proofofownership.com:7051
  - CORE_PEER_GOSSIP_EXTERNALENDPOINT=peer0.dm.proofofownership.com:7051
  - CORE_PEER_LOCALMSPID=DiamondManufacturerMSP
  - CORE_PEER_CHAINCODELISTENADDRESS=peer0.dm.proofofownership.com:7052
  #- CORE_PEER_TLS_ROOTCERT_FILE=/opt/gopath/src/github.com/hyperledger/fabric/peer/crypto/peerOrganizations/dm.proofofownership.com/peers/peer0.dm.proofofownership.com/tls/ca.crt
  #- CORE_PEER_TLS_ROOTCERT_FILE=/home/john/Proof-Of-Ownership/crypto-config/peerOrganizations/dm.proofofownership.com/peers/peer0.dm.proofofownership.com/tls/ca.crt
volumes:
    - /var/run/:/host/var/run/
    - ../crypto-config/peerOrganizations/dm.proofofownership.com/peers/peer0.dm.proofofownership.com/msp:/etc/hyperledger/fabric/msp
    - ../crypto-config/peerOrganizations/dm.proofofownership.com/peers/peer0.dm.proofofownership.com/tls:/etc/hyperledger/fabric/tls
    - peer0.dm.proofofownership.com:/var/hyperledger/production
ports:
  - 7051:7051
  - 7053:7053
```

**Orderer Configuration in "docker-compose-base.yaml" file:**

```
orderer.proofofownership.com:
container_name: orderer.proofofownership.com
image: hyperledger/fabric-orderer:x86_64-1.1.0
environment:
  # CORE_VM_DOCKER_HOSTCONFIG_NETWORKMODE Newly Added
  #- CORE_VM_DOCKER_HOSTCONFIG_NETWORKMODE=proof_of_ownership_pow
  #- CORE_VM_DOCKER_HOSTCONFIG_NETWORKMODE=pow
  - ORDERER_GENERAL_LOGLEVEL=DEBUG
  - ORDERER_GENERAL_LISTENADDRESS=0.0.0.0
  - ORDERER_GENERAL_GENESISMETHOD=file
  #- ORDERER_GENERAL_GENESISFILE=/var/hyperledger/orderer/orderer.genesis.block
  - ORDERER_GENERAL_GENESISFILE=/var/hyperledger/orderer/genesis.block
  - ORDERER_GENERAL_LOCALMSPID=OrdererMSP
  - ORDERER_GENERAL_LOCALMSPDIR=/var/hyperledger/orderer/msp
  # enabled TLS
  - ORDERER_GENERAL_TLS_ENABLED=true
  #- ORDERER_GENERAL_TLS_ENABLED=false
  - ORDERER_GENERAL_TLS_PRIVATEKEY=/var/hyperledger/orderer/tls/server.key
  - ORDERER_GENERAL_TLS_CERTIFICATE=/var/hyperledger/orderer/tls/server.crt
  - ORDERER_GENERAL_TLS_ROOTCAS=[/var/hyperledger/orderer/tls/ca.crt]
  # New Addition
  - CONFIGTX_ORDERER_ORDERERTYPE=solo
  - CONFIGTX_ORDERER_BATCHSIZE_MAXMESSAGECOUNT=10
  - CONFIGTX_ORDERER_BATCHTIMEOUT=2s
  - CONFIGTX_ORDERER_ADDRESSES=[127.0.0.1:7050]
#working_dir: /opt/gopath/src/github.com/hyperledger/fabric
working_dir: /opt/gopath/src/github.com/hyperledger/fabric/orderer
command: orderer
volumes:
- ../channel-artifacts/genesis.block:/var/hyperledger/orderer/genesis.block
- ../crypto-config/ordererOrganizations/proofofownership.com/orderers/orderer.proofofownership.com/msp:/var/hyperledger/orderer/msp
- ../crypto-config/ordererOrganizations/proofofownership.com/orderers/orderer.proofofownership.com/tls/:/var/hyperledger/orderer/tls
- orderer.proofofownership.com:/var/hyperledger/production/orderer
ports:
  - 7050:7050
```

I also reviewed the peer's docker container logs (using docker logs ) and received the following logs:

```
Launch -> ERRO 3eb launchAndWaitForRegister failed: timeout expired while starting chaincode CreateDiamond:1.0(networkid:dev,peerid:peer0.dm.proofofownership.com,tx:cc34a20176d7f09e1537b039f3340450e08f6447bf16965324655e72a2a58623)
2018-08-01 12:59:08.739 UTC [endorser] simulateProposal -> ERRO 3ed [dmanddis][cc34a201] failed to invoke chaincode name:"lscc" , error: timeout expired while starting chaincode CreateDiamond:1.0(networkid:dev,peerid:peer0.dm.proofofownership.com,tx:cc34a20176d7f09e1537b039f3340450e08f6447bf16965324655e72a2a58623)
```

**Following logs were received on installing chaincode:**

```
2018-08-03 09:44:55.822 UTC [msp] GetLocalMSP -> DEBU 001 Returning existing local MSP
2018-08-03 09:44:55.822 UTC [msp] GetDefaultSigningIdentity -> DEBU 002 Obtaining default signing identity
2018-08-03 09:44:55.822 UTC [chaincodeCmd] checkChaincodeCmdParams -> INFO 003 Using default escc
2018-08-03 09:44:55.822 UTC [chaincodeCmd] checkChaincodeCmdParams -> INFO 004 Using default vscc
2018-08-03 09:44:55.822 UTC [chaincodeCmd] getChaincodeSpec -> DEBU 005 java chaincode disabled
2018-08-03 09:44:58.270 UTC [golang-platform] getCodeFromFS -> DEBU 006 getCodeFromFS github.com/hyperledger/fabric/peer/chaincode
2018-08-03 09:45:02.089 UTC [golang-platform] func1 -> DEBU 007 Discarding GOROOT package bytes
2018-08-03 09:45:02.089 UTC [golang-platform] func1 -> DEBU 008 Discarding GOROOT package encoding/json
2018-08-03 09:45:02.089 UTC [golang-platform] func1 -> DEBU 009 Discarding GOROOT package fmt
2018-08-03 09:45:02.090 UTC [golang-platform] func1 -> DEBU 00a Discarding provided package github.com/hyperledger/fabric/core/chaincode/shim
2018-08-03 09:45:02.090 UTC [golang-platform] func1 -> DEBU 00b Discarding provided package github.com/hyperledger/fabric/protos/peer
2018-08-03 09:45:02.090 UTC [golang-platform] func1 -> DEBU 00c Discarding GOROOT package strconv
2018-08-03 09:45:02.090 UTC [golang-platform] func1 -> DEBU 00d skipping dir: /opt/gopath/src/github.com/hyperledger/fabric/peer/chaincode/go
2018-08-03 09:45:02.090 UTC [golang-platform] GetDeploymentPayload -> DEBU 00e done
2018-08-03 09:45:02.090 UTC [container] WriteFileToPackage -> DEBU 00f Writing file to tarball: src/github.com/hyperledger/fabric/peer/chaincode/CreateDiamond.go
2018-08-03 09:45:02.122 UTC [msp/identity] Sign -> DEBU 010 Sign: plaintext: 0AE3070A5B08031A0B089EC890DB0510...EC7BFE1B0000FFFFEE433C37001C0000
2018-08-03 09:45:02.122 UTC [msp/identity] Sign -> DEBU 011 Sign: digest: E5160DE95DB096379967D959FA71E692F098983F443378600943EA5D7265A82C 
2018-08-03 09:45:02.230 UTC [chaincodeCmd] install -> DEBU 012 Installed remotely response:<status:200 payload:"OK" >
2018-08-03 09:45:02.230 UTC [main] main -> INFO 013 Exiting.....
```

Comment: Did "chaincode install" work without problem? Can you send the orderer configuration too?

Comment: @PhilippeLabalette Yes I could install the chaincode without any issue. I have edited the post and added the orderer configuration in docker-compose-base.yaml file and the logs which came after installing the chaincode.

Comment: Did you find a solution for your issue?

Answer (score 1):

In the peer configuration, you specified a different port for the chaincode endpoint than the peer adress (chaincode endpoint port 7052, peer adress on port 7051):

```
CORE_PEER_CHAINCODELISTENADDRESS=peer0.dm.proofofownership.com:7052
```

But this port is not exposed. Please add this to your peer port configuration:

```
- 7052:7052
```

Comment: You could also try to comment this line:    CORE_PEER_CHAINCODELISTENADDRESS=peer0.dm.proofofownership.com:7052

Answer (score 0):

It is likely that your chaincode is failing on start-up. You might want to try using the development mode tutorial approach to debug your chaincode. It is possible that the chaincode process is failing. By executing from within the container, you can view the logs to see what might not be working for you.

The devmode tutorial is [here](https://hyperledger-fabric.readthedocs.io/en/release-1.2/chaincode4ade.html#testing-using-dev-mode) . You will simply need to replace the tutorial's chaincode with your own.